# Sort Anticlockwise the points of rectilinear polygon

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I am given a rectilinear polygon whose coordinates are given.
Please suggest to me a solution to sort anticlockwise, such that a closed line can be formed.

```
bool mycomparator(Point p1,Point p2){

    return ((p1.x*p2.y-p2.x*p1.y)>0);

}

void sort_anticlockwise(vector<Point> v){

    sort(v.begin(),v.end(),mycomparator);

}
```

But this is not working.
Please provide a solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting vertices of a polygon in CCW or CW direction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114378/sorting-vertices-of-a-polygon-in-ccw-or-cw-direction)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the other question @JimMischel points us at.  In that question the polygon is specified by both vertices and edges, here it seems that only the vertices are given.

Comment: Convert to polar coordinates with polygon centroid as origin, then sort by angle.

Comment: Sorting a rectilinear polygon's points by angle won't necessarily produce the correct line loop, if the polygon isn't convex. My instinct is that finding a simple rectilinear line loop for a set of vertices is NP-hard.

Comment: Is the polygon axis aligned? That would make it a lot easier.

Comment: yes the polygon is axis aligned

Comment: I've deleted my 'answer' after @NicoSchertler pointed out its fatal flaw. :-(

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Sorry ;)

Comment: @Ben Why wouldn't an incremental approach work?

Comment: It totally would (q.v. Nico down there). I'd forgotten that the vertices were *vertices*, rather than simply points contained in the polygon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the following polygon:

[image: Polygon]

First, order your vertices by y-coordinate. In groups of equal y-coordinate sort the vertices by x-coordinate:

[image: Sorted by y and x-coordinate]

There will always be an even number of vertices in each group if there are no degenerate vertices. Edges will always alternate. So there is an edge between 0-1, no edge between 1-2, edge between 2-3, no edge, edge etc.

[image: Add edges]

Store the associated edges for each vertex. E.g. in a map or in an appropriate structure.

Do the same for vertical edges (first sort by x-coordinate, in the groups sort by y-coordinate).

Then you have all edges of the polygon. Each vertex should now have 2 associated edges. Pick one vertex and go from edge to edge. This will give you the polyline. If you find that the line is in clockwise direction, just revert the order and you'll get a ccw polyline.