# Connect a list of points

Tags: c#

I have a list of points. I need lines to path through ALL of the points and create a convex hull.

```
var list = new List<PointD>()
{
    new PointD(1, 2),
    new PointD(1, -2),
    new PointD(4, 2),
    new PointD(2, 3),
    new PointD(2, 2),
    new PointD(2, -2),
    new PointD(4, -3),
    new PointD(2, -3),
    new PointD(4, -2),
    new PointD(6, 3),
    new PointD(6, -2),
    new PointD(5, 2),
    new PointD(5, 3),
    new PointD(4, 3)
};
```

What I need is a sorted list of points that can be connected by lines to make a polygon like below.

- The list of points are processed beforehand, so there is always an answer and no points will be left out.
- the points are connected by horizontal or vertical lines only

[image]

Comment: So, what is your question here exactly?

Comment: I want an algorithm to take a unsorted list of points and give me a sorted list of points so that I can connect them to create a polygon like above.

Comment: @AlexJolig I have been thinking but I have no idea so far!

Comment: This is not really a question. You should try something and come here to ask if you encounter a problem

Comment: I have tried but found nothing so far!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort Anticlockwise the points of rectilinear polygon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862162/sort-anticlockwise-the-points-of-rectilinear-polygon)

Comment: @NicoSchertler Thanks!

Comment: How would you do this by hand? In the end, for any point in the list, only a few others can be used to form a horiz/vert line from it.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Exactly. But the question is how to start it right and efficiently. You may connect two points and then find out that you should not have!

Comment: Have you tried implementing any of the algorithms mentioned on [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_convex_hull)?

Comment: @Alexey Thanks, I had not seen this. I will try these out.

Answer (score -2):

So, to sum up comments, you can look [Sort Anticlockwise the points of rectilinear polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862162/sort-anticlockwise-the-points-of-rectilinear-polygon) or [Orthogonal convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_convex_hull).

Comment: The Orthogonal convex hull wont work, as the resulting orthogonal polygon could not be orthoconvex. In the provided example the algorithm for orthognal convex hull would let out the third and fourth points, counting in counter clockwise order, starting from the bottom-most and right-most point.