# Creating an algorithm to convert a pixel sprite into a rectilinear polygon

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, sprite, polygon, feature-extraction

I am attempting to write an algorithm that would convert any pixel sprite to a set of vertices that compose a rectilinear polygon. My algorithm worked fine for sprites that have been scaled up. When I tested my algorithm on more size accurate sprites, I ran into the edge case that a single pixel might represent 2 vertices that are connected to each other.

I plan on passing the set of vertices into the rectilinear sorting algorithm detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17863840), so that I can produce a fully connected polyline.

```
# Edge case: The Pixel is protruding from the image. That means that the pixel is only connected on main side with the 2 diagonal sides being non transparent. i.e tetris T block eg:

+---+---+---+
| x | x | x |
+---+---+---+
| x | x | x |
+---+---+---+
|   | x |   |
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
```

How do I go about converting this pixel into a vertex. And how would the following shape be represented as a polygon.

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   | x |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | x | x | x |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   | x |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Here is my code for extracting the points:

```py
def reduce_to_polygon(image):
    # Find the dimensions of the image
    width, height = image.size

    points = []
    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            # Check if the pixel is transparent
            if image.getpixel((x, y))[3] == 0:
                continue

            if is_corner_pixel(image, x, y):
                points.append({'x': x, 'y': y})

    return points
```

And here is the `is_corner_pixel` definition:

```py
def is_corner_pixel(image, x, y):
    # Calc head of time to simplify the conditons
    is_trans_top = image.getpixel((x, y-1))[3] == 0 if y > 0 else True
    is_trans_bottom = image.getpixel((x, y+1))[3] == 0 if y < image.height-1 else True

    is_trans_left = image.getpixel((x-1, y))[3] == 0 if x > 0 else True
    is_trans_right = image.getpixel((x+1, y))[3] == 0 if x < image.width-1 else True

    is_trans_top_left = image.getpixel((x-1, y-1))[3] == 0 if x > 0 and y > 0 else True
    is_trans_top_right = image.getpixel((x+1, y-1))[3] == 0 if x < image.width-1 and y > 0 else True

    is_trans_bottom_left = image.getpixel((x-1, y+1))[3] == 0 if x > 0 and y < image.height-1 else True
    is_trans_bottom_right = image.getpixel((x+1, y+1))[3] == 0 if x < image.width-1 and y < image.height-1 else True

    # Edge case: The Pixel is protruding from the image. That means that the pixel is only connected on main side with
    # the 2 diagnoal sides being non transparent. i.e tetris T block eg:
    #
    #     +---+---+---+
    #     |   |   |   |
    #     +---+---+---+
    #     | 0 | * | 0 |
    #     +---+---+---+
    #     | 0 | 0 | 0 |
    #     +---+---+---+
    #
    if (not is_trans_top_left and not is_trans_top and not is_trans_top_right and is_trans_right and is_trans_bottom_right and is_trans_bottom and is_trans_bottom_left and is_trans_left) \
        or (not is_trans_top_right and not is_trans_right and not is_trans_bottom_right and is_trans_bottom and is_trans_bottom_left and is_trans_left and is_trans_top_left and is_trans_top) \
        or (not is_trans_bottom_right and not is_trans_bottom and not is_trans_bottom_left and is_trans_left and is_trans_top_left and is_trans_top and is_trans_top_right and is_trans_right) \
        or (not is_trans_bottom_left and not is_trans_left and not is_trans_top_left and is_trans_top and is_trans_top_right and is_trans_right and is_trans_bottom_right and is_trans_bottom):
            TODO("Figure this out")

    # Check for convex corner pixels. A convex corner pixel must have atleast 3 neighbors be transparent and the
    # neighbors must be adjacent to one another and one of them must be a diagonal pixel. eg:
    #
    #     +---+---+---+
    #     | 0 | 0 |   |
    #     +---+---+---+
    #     | 0 | * |   |
    #     +---+---+---+
    #     |   |   |   |
    #     +---+---+---+
    #
    if (is_trans_left and is_trans_top_left and is_trans_top) \
        or (is_trans_top and is_trans_top_right and is_trans_right) \
        or (is_trans_right and is_trans_bottom_right and is_trans_bottom) \
        or (is_trans_bottom and is_trans_bottom_left and is_trans_left):
        return True

    # Check for concave corner pixels. A concave corner pixel must have exactly one diagonal neighbor be
    # transparent. eg:
    #
    #     +---+---+---+
    #     | 0 |   |   |
    #     +---+---+---+
    #     |   | * |   |
    #     +---+---+---+
    #     |   |   |   |
    #     +---+---+---+
    #
    if (is_trans_top_left and not is_trans_top and not is_trans_top_right and not is_trans_right and not is_trans_bottom_right and not is_trans_bottom and not is_trans_bottom_left and not is_trans_left) \
        or (is_trans_top_right and not is_trans_right and not is_trans_bottom_right and not is_trans_bottom and not is_trans_bottom_left and not is_trans_left and not is_trans_top_left and not is_trans_top) \
        or (is_trans_bottom_right and not is_trans_bottom and not is_trans_bottom_left and not is_trans_left and not is_trans_top_left and not is_trans_top and not is_trans_top_right and not is_trans_right) \
        or (is_trans_bottom_left and not is_trans_left and not is_trans_top_left and not is_trans_top and not is_trans_top_right and not is_trans_right and not is_trans_bottom_right and not is_trans_bottom):
        return True

    return False
```

Comment: So the coordinates of your polygon's coordinate system correspond to the pixels in the image? Why not make the coordinates correspond to the corners of the pixels instead? Then you can easily include single protruding pixels in every possible case.

Comment: My goal is to later connect the points together with a line to form a rectilinear polygon. The issue with protruding points is how to connect them with rest of the polygon.

Comment: I understand that, that's exactly why I ask. If you define the coordinates at the pixel corners instead of the pixel centers, then the task becomes very easy. I.e., such that the first pixel has its corners in `(0,0), (1,0), (0,1), (1,1)`. Can you do it this way?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do that since each pixel coordinates is mapped 1-to-1 with where I would display each the polygon.  I don't think it's possible for me to further subdivide the pixels for more precision.

Comment: When you say "My goal is to later connect the points together with a line to form a rectilinear polygon.", is the objective to build the outer polygonal envelope ? In this case you may remove all pixels surrounded by 4 other pixels.

Comment: I think the approach given by @Berthur may be most suitable, since I plan on passing the points into this [sorting algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17863840), and I don't see how just removing the other pixels is gonna work with it. The problem I'm facing is how to deal pixels that represent 2 connected vertices.